# ActionBar like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, whatsapp

How I make an actionbar like whatsapp, who changes buttons when fragments changes.

**Example:**

When i'm in "Conver..." tab I've baloon icon, when I swipe to "Chamadas" tab I a icon change to dial icon

[image]
how I can make this, programatically on android(java) ?

**My Drawer Activity**

```
@EActivity(R.layout.drawer)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.main)
public class DrawerActivity extends Activity {

    private Fragment fragment;

    @StringArrayRes(R.array.wigo_items)
    String[] mWigoItems;

    @ViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @ViewById(R.id.left_drawer)
    ListView mDrawerList;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle = "";

    @Bean
    MoodAdapter adapterKarma;

    @AfterViews
    public void afterViews() {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
             */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mWigoItems));
        // adapterKarma.moods.addAll(setListKarma());
        // mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterKarma);
        // mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerListItemClicked(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
        // view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // if((fragment.getClass() != TweetList_.class &&
        // TweetList_.class.isAssignableFrom(fragment.getClass()))){
        // Handle your other action bar items...
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
        case R.id.action_bookmark:
        case R.id.action_calendar:
        case R.id.action_sobre:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not implemented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @ItemClick(R.id.left_drawer)
    void mDrawerListItemClicked(int position) {

        fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TweetFragment_();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ConfigFragment_();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AboutFragment_();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        //setTitle(mWigoItems[position]);
        setTitle("");
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    public ArrayList<Mood> setListKarma() {

        // Now i have taken static values by loop.
        // For further inhancement we can take data by webservice / json / xml;
        ArrayList<Mood> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<Mood>();
        CustomListViewValuesArr
                .add(new Mood(1, "Apaixonado", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apaixonado)));

        return CustomListViewValuesArr;

    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- navigation drawer -->

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You are significantly more likely to get help from people if you include an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Vorticity as you wish

Comment: I'm using AndroidAnnotations Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Have your fragments call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreate()`.

Step #2: Implement `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` on your fragments.

Step #3: Move all action items that are specific to the fragments out of your activity and into the fragments.

Action bar items defined in fragments will only be in the action bar when those fragments are visible. Hence, as the user switches tabs, the contents of the action bar will change.